# Is it possible to configure an Excel add-in to use SAML2 authentication from Azure AD?

Tags: office365, saml-2.0

I have an excel add-in written in C# which communicates with a backend server in java, and I'd like to implement SAML2 from Azure AD

I've seen some examples in Microsoft docs, but they seem to use openid as a protocol. Is it even possible with SAML 2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question in Microsoft Q&A hoping to get a verified answer from Microsoft employees and experts and got one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/962203/is-it-possible-to-configure-an-excel-add-in-to-use.html

**Unfortunately for now it SAML doesn't support this feature**